# PostgreSQL performance of INSERT INTO table SELECT vs. COPY

Tags: postgresql, performance

I'm attempting to move medium amounts of data around in PostgreSQL (tens-to-hundreds of millions of rows).

In designing the system, I'm trying to understand: How does the performance of `INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) SELECT field1, field2 FORM other_table` compared with `COPY FROM ... BINARY` in PostgreSQL?

I can't find any documentation that directly speaks to that question. Some considerations I can see:

- `INTO INTO ... SELECT` requires both reads and writes from the same disk
- `COPY FROM ... BINARY` requires either a client that has the data, or doing a round-trip `COPY TO ...` piped to `COPY FROM ...`

But I'm sure there are others, I'm hoping there's some form of canonical performance guidance around comparative expectations for these.

Comment: "requires both reads and writes from the same disk"  It is possible that doing that would interfere with each other and cause performance problems, but it really depends on how clever your kernel and filesystem are.  That is not something that PostgreSQL can address.  You will have to try it on your system and see.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately questions like this can only be answered by tests.

But if you want to copy data from one table to another, `INSERT ... SELECT ...` should perform better, because it does not require saving the data to an intermediary file or going through a client-server connection.

Tips for speed:

- Have no constraints and indexes on the new table when you load the data, but add them afterwards.
- Make sure `max_wal_size` is high.

I'd `VACUUM (FREEZE)` the new table afterwards (which doesn't disturb normal work on the table) to make future anti-wraparound autovacuum runs fast.

Comment: One consideration that occurs to me -- does `INSERT ... SELECT` require buffering the entire results of the `SELECT` query in memory, or does it stream the results?

Comment: It should stream, unless you have things like `ORDER BY` or `DISTINCT` in the query.